# Not able to create provisioning profile/bundle identifier with enterprise account having capability Sign In with apple

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, sign-in-with-apple, apple-developer-account

Apologies if this question doesn't make any sense, I just integrated Sign in with apple in my app with my **Developer** account, Everything works great. Then I needed to provide build to the clients and when I was creating a bundle Identifier for my app from an **Enterprise** account I didn't see the sign in with Apple **Capability**. I searched over the internet and didn't find anything yet.

**Is there anything I'm missing?**

Attaching the screenshot of the developer and enterprise account.

**Developer**

[image]

**Enterprise**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign-in with Apple isn't available for Enterprise signed apps;  Sign-in with Apple is essentially a consumer-facing solution intended as an alternative to social network sign-in such as  Facebook or Google.

Enterprise apps are only for distribution to employees of the enterprise.  A social log in doesn't make sense in that case; typically it would be expected that the employee would sign in with their employer-provided credentials (e.g. Active Directory).

If you are looking to provide a build to a client for testing you should either use an ad-hoc build with their test device UUIDs or TestFlight.  Using the Enterprise program to distribute apps outside of your own enterprise is a violation of the terms of that program.

Comment: Thanks for the correct information, now comes another case. What if you want to test the app in your organization? do we need to remove apple sign-in capability?

Comment: Again, TestFlight would probably be the most appropriate tool, as if you are going to deploy an app that uses Sign In With Apple in your own organisation you would need to do so as a Custom B2B app.  To be honest, unless you are doing something that simply won't get approved by Apple there isn't much need for the Enterprise program any more now that organisations can "sell" B2B apps to themselves.

Comment: @Paulw11 has right. But I just want to point out that you can use Single-Sign On Extension in Enterprise program if your app really needs authentication. For more information watch this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/301/